# Android Studio error in build - Cause: startElement.getAttributeByName(QName("name")) must not be null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I want to create a spinner widget, and I added this to `string.xml`:

```
    <string-array name="options">
        <item>All Tasks</item>
        <item>Today's Tasks</item>
        <item>Tomorrow's Tasks</item>
        <item>Archived Tasks</item>
    </string-array>
```

and I adapted it:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and I got a build error:

```
Cause: startElement.getAttributeByName(QName("name")) must not be null
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special character like apostrophe(') are not allowed in xml directly
Use can use escape sequences to get the desired result.

Replace:
Today's by Today \ 's

**Use a \ backslash symbol before apostrophe '**

Answer (score 2):

In String.xml

replace 'String which you have entered' to String which you have entered

or simply remove ' ' these

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

By :

```
final String options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please let me know if this works.
Thank you

Comment: No. The problem was `. The sign ' is not usable.

Comment: Yes. I needed to change "today's tasks" to todays tasks, and add ' - via code